# Windows 8 store resolution requirements

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-store

What are the resolution requirements for a windows 8 store app? Does the app have to be auto fullscreen or am I able to set a size such as 600px * 600px for the apps container?

Comment: Your app may run at any size, as long as that size is "fullscreen."

Comment: Thanks James McNellis. Helps clear things up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default your app should run on any resolution. Below are guidelines from MS:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh780612.aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2012/03/21/scaling-to-different-screens.aspx